# Config files in a custom Symfony compatible library

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, configuration, drupal-8

Ok, so I am working on creating a custom standalone library that I intend to use in a Drupal 8 site. Drupal 8 runs on Symfony 2.8.x. I want this code to be usable outside Drupal. So I have focused on making it more Symfony oriented than Drupal oriented.

What I have found, thus far, with all my searching, is that Symfony requires you to write a bunch of config declarations in DependencyInjection/Configuration.php. As well as service declarations in a MyBundleExtension.php file.

What I have NOT found is a simple way to say "Hey, I want this config parameter in this standalone (not at all a controller) class". So I wrote the class you see below.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Code: http://pastebin.com/pdp53kxe

Also, will this create any problems with loading services?

At some point I have to deal with dependency injection and actually new up what we want to inject. Still not sure how I will work that into this standalone library while utilizing the Symfony framework. So suggestions as to how to have Symfony wire that up for me would be great.

My basic question here is about using Symfony in a library setting. Where you would not expect to just need the variables within a controller context.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said if you want to import configuration  you need to use your `DependecyInjection/MyBundleExtension.php` class to load the config (maybe even parse) yourself.

Another way is to use compiler passes to directly manipulate the container but this looks like it would be an overkill for your case.

The main reason is that the Dependency Injection Container (wich contains all your service definitions and config parameters) is compiled.

So you have to inject your extra config before the compilation.

Helpful links:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/import.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html